# MVC validation messages - localization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I have a problem. On main server and localhost are the exacly the same files.

But in localhost I have messages in my home language, like

`Pole Email jest wymagane.`

And on main server I have:

`The Email field is required.`

As I said, files are exacly the same. 
How to resolve it?

Comment: What language do you want, local or English? Your Main server is probably set to an English Culture.

Comment: Add `<globalization uiCulture="pl-PL">` for polish culture or `<globalization uiCulture="en-Us">` for english one. UICulture is responsible for retrieving correct resources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you happen to have

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto">...</globalization>
```

in your `web.config`? This would automatically switch the culture of the site to suit the language passed via the browser request i.e. `Accept-Language`.

If you want to force the language from the server just set `enableClientBasedCulture` to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the solution for me was to install the correspondant language package in the server (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14236/language-packs). Inmediatly after that, the validation messages started appearing in the desired language.